MAUI App Intermittently Stops Connecting to ASP.NET Core Web API (Using Dev Tunnels)
I am developing a .NET MAUI app that connects to an ASP.NET Core Web API using Visual Studio Dev Tunnels for local development. Initially, the connection works perfectly, and the app communicates with the API as expected. However, after some time, the app stops connecting to the API. This issue occurs intermittently—sometimes it works one day and then stops the next day, and so on.
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:
Verified that the Dev Tunnel is active and accessible from a browser on the same machine.
Ensured that the API URL matches the Dev Tunnel address (using HTTPS).
Restarted both the API and the MAUI app, but the issue persists after a while.
Tested on an Android device (not emulator), with the same results.
Environment Details:
MAUI Version: (mention the exact version you are using)
ASP.NET Core Version: (mention your framework version, e.g., 6.0, 7.0, etc.)
Visual Studio Version: (e.g., Visual Studio 2022 v17.x)
Device: Samsung SM-A528B (Android 13, API Level 33)
Dev Tunnel Configuration: HTTPS enabled

Not that MAUI doesn't have its issues, but I would search for something like this: https://github.com/microsoft/dev-tunnels/issues/400, before focusing my attention on the platform.

“Stops connecting” is a pretty vague description.  What is the specific behavior that occurs when it can’t connect?

@Jason The dev tunnel seems to stop connecting after some time, though I don’t see any specific errors. What I’ve observed is that when my MAUI app tries to make a request to the API, there’s no response. For example, everything worked perfectly yesterday, but after a while, it stopped. When this happens, I can’t access the API link from my phone either. However, when the app is working fine, I’m able to open the API in my phone’s browser without any issues. It seems to be some limitation with the dev tunnel. I’m still investigating.

@H.A.H. I noticed that the dev tunnel stops working after a few hours. I’m not exactly sure why, but I’ve identified that the issue lies with the dev tunnel itself.

@AlionaC Indeed. Read the link I gave you. It is bad news for you.
